# database in App_Data not persisting data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, fluent-nhibernate

I have a a sql database in my app_data folder and my connection string looks like this:

`Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|wikipediamaze.mdf; Trusted_Connection=Yes;`

I'm using Fluent Nhibernate, and everything is mapped properly. I'm able to connect to the database fine and even update and insert rows with no problem.

My issue is that once I stop debugging, none of my data is there. I've checked to see if perhaps my database was being put in the bin folder and a new instance was being created for every time I ran the app, but this is not the case.

Does anyone have any other suggestions? I've spent 2 nights now trying to figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is this connection string you mention located? There are multiple places the connection string can reside. Perhaps you have a duplicate.

Comment: I only have 1 connection string and it's in the settings file which I reference through the properties class in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was that I was improperly using the NHibernate session. I needed to call ISession.Flush or ITransaction.Commit to persist it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you do not commit your changes. Start SQL Profiler and you'll see exactly what SQL is run against your database.

Comment: Is there something special I need to do commit the changes orther than session.Save(myObj); ?